# Recyclerview old item view doesn't remove when click another item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview . I click on a item. It is highlighted ( sets background - color) . And then, I click another item , It doesn't remove old highlighted view. My class is very leak . Also could you give me an advice to make more effective ?

```
public class DrawerMenuShelfListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerMenuShelfListAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int selectedRow = 0;

    public Fragment fragment;
    public ViewHolder holder;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private ArrayList<ShelfModel> shelfList;

    public DrawerMenuShelfListAdapter(Fragment fragment, ArrayList<ShelfModel> shelfList, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.shelfList = shelfList;
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    }

    public void setItemSelected(int position){
        recyclerView.getChildAt(selectedRow).setBackgroundColor(fragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        notifyItemChanged(selectedRow);
        selectedRow = position;
        recyclerView.getChildAt(selectedRow).setBackgroundColor(fragment.getActivity().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
        notifyItemChanged(selectedRow);
    }

    public void updateList(ArrayList<ShelfModel> list){
        shelfList.clear();
        shelfList.addAll(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        notifyItemChanged(selectedRow);
    }

    @Override
    public DrawerMenuShelfListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_list_row, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder(v);
        holder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.definitionText);
        holder.total = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.countText);
        holder.editButton = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        holder.text.setTypeface(App.MUSEO_100);
        holder.total.setTypeface(App.MUSEO_300);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ShelfModel shelfModel = shelfList.get(position);
        holder.text.setText(shelfModel.getName());
        holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(shelfModel.getTotal()));
        holder.shelfId = shelfModel.getShelfId();
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return shelfList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(v);
        ((DrawerMenuShelfListListener)fragment).onShelfItemClick(shelfList.get(position));
        setItemSelected(position);

    }

    public interface DrawerMenuShelfListListener extends BaseRecyclerViewListener {
        void onShelfItemClick(ShelfModel shelfModel);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public TextView total;
        public ImageView editButton;
        public int shelfId;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the solution.If I don't call notifyItemChanged , it works